# The closure of $(f)$ for $f\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

In Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry, there is this claim:

> Let $f(x,y)\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ be irreducible and let $\eta=(f)\in \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb C[x,y])$. Then the closure of $\{\eta\}$ consists of $\eta$ together with all closed points $(a,b)$ for which $f(a,b)=0$.

I don't get why this is true. We have that
$$\overline{\{\eta\}}=V(f)=\{p\in\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb C[x,y]):f\in p\}.$$
Now clearly this set contains $\eta$ together with all maximal ideals $(x-a,y-a)$ such that $f(a,b)=0$. But what about the converse? If $f\in p$ and $p$ is prime and not equal to $(f)$, why would $p$ be maximal?

Comment: Because $\Bbb C[x,y]$ has Krull dimension $2$?